# How to force a WiX bootstrapper to download an MSI package?

Tags: wix, wix3.6

I'm reading [this section of WiX toolset manual](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/authoring_bundle_package_manifest.htm), and wondering, how to force WiX bootstrapper to download an [MSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer) package? For example, before installing my application, the bootstrapper has to download and install:

- .NET Framework Client Profile
- SQL Server 2008 R2 Shared Management Objects.

I've thought, I can describe corresponding `MsiPackage` like this:

but [the schema reference](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_msipackage.htm) for `MsiPackage` element tells, that

> "At a minimum, the SourceFile or Name attribute must be specified."

And, of course, it doesn't lie - without `SourceFile` or `Name` the bundle project compiles with errors.

Adding `RemotePayload` to `MsiPackage` like this:

```
  <MsiPackage Name="redist\SharedManagementObjects.msi"
              DisplayName="Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Objects"
              DisplayInternalUI="yes"
              Vital="yes"
              DownloadUrl="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=188438&amp;clcid=0x409">
    <RemotePayload Size="10953728"
                   Version="10.50.1600.1"
                   ProductName="Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Objects"
                   Description="Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Objects"
                   Hash="6ce3a433309c63d98bcf0e2b9f1dfaed8cc18783"/>
  </MsiPackage>
```

causes an build error:

> Unable to read package ''. This installation package could not be
>   opened. Verify that the package exists and that you can access it, or
>   contact the application vendor to verify that this is a valid Windows
>   Installer package.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar question answered [here](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Remote-MSI-Payload-td7579500.html):

> That's not supported today; RemotePayload supports only the fields
>   needed to verify a downloaded file is what's expected but nothing more
>   than that. That works for .exes because Burn treats those like black
>   boxes. Burn gathers a lot more data from MSI packages.
>
> So the bug is either that it's an allowed child of MsiPackage or that
>   it doesn't yet support all the data needed from an MSI.